How to extract a text between \n character, may have texts between \n character multiple times using SQL Server
I need to write a stored procedure which takes response from API and save values in local DB.For example, I have a string like this "Image is Non-compliant \nFace Covered \nIncorrect Lighting \n". I need to extract the text between \n character like Face Covered and Incorrect Lighting.
How to write a SQL query to extract the text and the string length may vary?
I tried with
SELECT SUBSTRING('Image is Non-compliant \nFace Covered \nIncorrect Lighting \n',
                 CHARINDEX('\n','Image is Non-compliant \nFace Covered \nIncorrect Lighting \n')+2, 
                 CHARINDEX('\n','Image is Non-compliant \nFace Covered \nIncorrect Lighting \n', CHARINDEX('\n','Image is Non-compliant \nFace Covered \nIncorrect Lighting \n')+1) -
                 CHARINDEX('\n','Image is Non-compliant \nFace Covered \nIncorrect Lighting \n')-2) AS My_String.

But the output I'm getting is only Face Covered.
But I need to extract whatever the text which is between \n dynamically

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

FYI usually the best way to achieve things like this is to split out your data before it reaches your database. String operations in SQL (such as STRING_SPLIT) can be expensive and unnecessary.
